# C++ using private and public in macro, inside class

Tags: c++, padding

Im trying to make a macro for padding my classes which i use in game hacking. Let me show you what i am trying to do:

```
#define pad(loc, size)  private: \
                    char _pad#loc[#size]; \
                    public:
```

then i want to use it like:

```
class C_VTable {
public:
   float member;          // <- public
   pad(0x4, 0x30);        // <- private im not sure how to make the pad name be like pad0x4
   float anothermember;   // <- public again
};
```

How can i do this, because i get an error saying it expected a ;
a little messy, but i hope you understand.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: @FredLarson edited. forgot to ask it..

Comment: Write `pad(0x4, 0x30)` without `;`

Comment: `#` creates a string literal, use `##` to glue `__pad` and `log` together

Comment: Identifiers with a double underscore are reserved. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/10077.

Comment: When debugging macro problems, it sometimes helps to look at the output of the preprocessor to see what it did with your macro. Every compiler I know of has an option to run just the preprocessor. It's usually a variant of -E.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `##` paste operator to combine two tokens together.  Also, don't stringify the size using `#` - you don't want a string inside the square brackets.

```
#define pad(loc, size)  private: \
                    char __pad##loc[size]; \
                    public:
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Another question, if i do pad( 0x7AE, 2 ) is the pad name going to be __pad0x7AE[2], __pad7AE[2] or __pad1966[2] (7AEh)?

Comment: The field name will be `__pad0x7AE`.  The token gets pasted raw just as you spelled it.